# Split-brain discovery in Hazelcast cluster in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast, multicast, vert.x

I have the following setup.

My Vert.x verticles are clustered with Hazelcast and deployed on Kubernetes cluster with following network info:

```
------------------------------------------------
           TCP/IP NETWORK INFORMATION
------------------------------------------------
IP Entered = ..................: 10.60.0.0
CIDR = ........................: /14
Netmask = .....................: 255.252.0.0
Netmask (hex) = ...............: 0xfffc0000
Wildcard Bits = ...............: 0.3.255.255
------------------------------------------------
Network Address = .............: 10.60.0.0
Broadcast Address = ...........: 10.63.255.255
Usable IP Addresses = .........: 262,142
First Usable IP Address = .....: 10.60.0.1
Last Usable IP Address = ......: 10.63.255.254
```

The Hazelcast's `cluster.xml` has the following section:

```
<join>
  <multicast enabled="true">
    <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
    <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
  </multicast>
</join>
```

All seems fine. When I start verticles in pods, I get the output (abbreviated):

```
>kubectl get pods --namespace develop -o wide

READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP        
1/1     Running   0          52m   10.60.4.18
1/1     Running   0          4m    10.60.6.19
1/1     Running   0          4m    10.60.1.16
1/1     Running   0          4m    10.60.1.18
1/1     Running   0          4m    10.60.6.18  
1/1     Running   0          4m    10.60.1.17
1/1     Running   0          4m    10.60.4.23
1/1     Running   0          8m    10.60.6.17
1/1     Running   0          4m    10.60.4.22
1/1     Running   0          4m    10.60.4.21
1/1     Running   0          4m    10.60.6.20
1/1     Running   0          5d    10.60.4.9
```

The problem is, that the clusters are groupped not by the group name specified, but rather by the 3rd number of the ip address. So, I'm getting a cluster of:

```
                      masterAddress=[10.60.1.17]:5701
                      Members[
                              [10.60.1.17]:5701
                              [10.60.1.16]:5701
                              [10.60.1.18]:5701]]
```

then 5 members for "cluster" `10.60.4.*`, 4 members for `10.60.6.*` and so on and they are not merging...

What am I missing?

TIA

Comment: Most likely the cluster members doesn't have access to other subnets. Can you please share the full log of a member? We can see if it discovered other members or not.

Comment: I wouldn't use multicast on Kubernetes. The Vert.x Hazelcast cluster manager has [documentation](https://vertx-ci.github.io/web-site-snapshot/docs/vertx-hazelcast/java/#_configuring_for_kubernetes) for Kubernetes deployment. It's not on the official website yet (in master branch, will be when 3.6 is released).

Comment: @tsegismont well we used to have it running with `com.hazelcast:hazelcast-kubernetes:1.0.0` plugin but it had some limitations that all pods would have to run on the same ip address (as our devops-guy explained me). With multicast we could use different IPs. What I don't understand now, is why multicast works but creating several clusters instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Hazelcast has a dedicated plugin for the discovery in Kubernetes. Please check: [hazelcast-kubernetes](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes).

Mutlicast may or may not work, since it depends on the underlying network. In my experience on GKE, it sometimes works, sometimes it doesn't. That is why multicast-based discovery is never recommended for Kubernetes.

Resources:

- [Hazelcast Kubernetes README](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes/blob/master/README.md)
- [Hazelcast Kubernetes Code Sample](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/kubernetes)
- [Sample Spring Boot application with Hazelcast Embedded deployed on Kubernetes](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/kubernetes/samples/embedded)